# How to allow number in Input type number outside min and max range

Tags: jquery, html

```
<form>
<input type="number" min="10" max="100" value="0"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Hi the above code will not allow 0. I want to allow all numbers between 10 and 100. But if the user does not enter any value or enters 0 it also must be allowed. How can i do this?

Comment: what ?? this seems pretty contradictory

Comment: do you need the validity error message from browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't specify this with HTMl itself. But you can use jquery and javascript validation.

```
<form id="validateme" action="post.php">
    <input id="number" type="number" value="0"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
$('#validateme').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    if($('#number').value == 0 || $('#number').value >= 10 && $('#number').value <= 100) {
        this.submit(); // If the validation suceeds
    } else {
        alert('Validation failed');
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps and works ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1">
<input id="number-field" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0"/>
<input class="form-submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/7de9L48q/1/